MKFIFO fails when one side is initiated from PHP - LINUX
I have two very simple C programs, say A and B that happily chat using mkfifo(). If I execute B from the command line, data pops up in A , all good. However, if I execute B from PHP using passthru() or exec() , no data is passed as it fails to open the fifo file, permission  denied.
I have put the command 'B' in a shell-script and run that from PHP, still the same. I guess its a permisions issue of some sort but I feel I've set all permissions. Any help , pointers or workarounds will stop me losing the plot completely. Thanks

Did you try executing the PHP script via CLI?

No I haven't. I'll Google it and give it a go. . I'm actually POSTing to the PHP from Javascript

This is most likely a permissions problem. Scripts run from the webserver are in a user like www-data, which may not have permission to create the fifo.

Please include the [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having.  We can't help you debug code we cannot see.

Hi Toby,  I will try to attached the sources.  So a.c listens , b.c sends , testPrint.c just prints a line to prove passthru is running a compiled executable from php and sendToC.php is the php I am trying get to pass data to the a.c file. ( My end goal is to pass data JS->PHP->C and have the C reply to the page )

PROBLEM Solved. ( sorry not sure how to flag this correctly) . As Barmar suggested its was a permission issue. Although I was opening with 0666 permission ( rwrwrw) , it only actualy created 664 ( rwrwr- ) andso 'other' had no wite access., even when starting 'a' as root. So I have done a system("chmod. a+rw ... ") and it all tickertyboo. Many thanks for the help everybody.

Hi there. If this isn't a duplicate issue, go ahead and post the resolution as an answer and accept it. It's a rather trivial error but may help someone else making the same mistake.

SOLVED - A permissions issue. mkfifo(filename , 0666 ) does not set rw-rw-rw permissions as you would reasonably expect. SeeExplanaion of why. I circumvented it by doing an explicit chmod after the mkfifo, although the hyper link has a more 'correct' solution.
